# How can I read in image dataset as numpy array in a memory efficient manner?

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I am trying to load in a dataset of images as a numpy array. How can I do this so that I don't stress the limits of RAM on my local machine, or create an array that requires too much memory? The larger set of images is the training set, which totals to be about 2GB of images.

This is to train a residual neural network that requires the input data to be a numpy array. I have used modules glob, PIL, skimage, sklearn, and numpy in an attempt to do load the images, but I am doing so in a likely naïve way since the ~2GB of images becomes a ~17(!) GB numpy array. I have tried searching for solutions, examples, and such, but am rather new to Python so the process is very slow.

The code used to load images naïvely is

```py
import glob
from skimage.transform import resize
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from PIL import Image

def root_2_numpy(data_root):
    """
    Load raw images and output a numpy array of all images and numpy array of labels
    Also preprocesses each image to (224,224) using anti-aliasing
    """
    # load images into numpy array
    all_image_paths = list(data_root.glob('*/*'))  # get image paths
    all_image_paths = [str(path) for path in all_image_paths]  # convert to string
    image_ds = np.zeros([len(all_image_paths), 224, 224,3])  # initialize image dataset
    for i in range(len(all_image_paths)):
        print(i)
        im = Image.open(all_image_paths[i])  # read image as RGB using matplotlib
        if im.mode == 'RGBA' or im.mode == 'L' or im.mode == 'CMYK':
            im = im.convert('RGB')
        elif im.mode =='P':
            im = im.convert('RGBA')
            im = im.convert('RGB')
        im = np.array(im)
        im = resize(im, (224,224), anti_aliasing=True)  # resize image using skimage
        image_ds[i,:,:,:] = im

    # load labels into numpy array
    label_ds = datasets.load_files(data_root, load_content=False, shuffle=False)  # get labels
    n_classes = len(label_ds.target_names)
    Y_ds = np.eye(len(label_ds.target_names))[label_ds.target.reshape(-1)]

    return image_ds, Y_ds, n_classes
```

I expected this to return a numpy array of ~2GB which has dimension (N, W, H, C) for number of images, image width, image height, and 3 channels for the images. It's not the issue at hand here, but I also expect to have data for the labels which are the category names in the root.

In addition to helping me load the data in efficiently, I would greatly appreciate insight on how my code creates such a large numpy array. As I write this, I have a feeling it is when converting the image types for non RBG images and perhaps creating more images than intended.

Comment: What is the value of `len(all_image_paths)`?

Comment: len(all_image_paths) returns 11

Answer (score 0):

The default data type of an array created by `numpy.zeros` is 64 bit floating point.  So `image_ds = np.zeros([len(all_image_paths), 224, 224,3])` creates an array that is 8 times bigger than you need.  Add the `dtype` parameter so that `image_ds` has data type `uint8` (8 bit unsigned integers):

```
image_ds = np.zeros([len(all_image_paths), 224, 224,3], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried your solution and it works. However, I still end up with a 17gb array after calling X_train.nbytes. Though, I didn't seem to have trouble with RAM using np.uint8 as the data type.